# Compatibility of Open GL 2.0 vs 1.1 on Android

Tags: android, opengl-es, version

Hi we're developing a live wallpaper application for android handsets,  our coding team is saying that openGL 1.1 should be used instead of openGL 2.0.

http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/opengl.html

This shows that openGL 2.0 is supported on 90% of devices accessing the market,  our coding team says that the software supports it but hardware acceleration and support would be an issue on many devices running android 2.2 and above. Anyone have any issues with openGL 2.0 and Android?

Comment: Nope if the device supports GLES 2 I've had no issues.

Answer (score 1):

I think most devices that support OpenGL ES 2 have appropriate hardware acceleration.

A lot of the newer devices actually emulate OpenGL ES 1.1 support using
OpenGL ES 2.0 and so would need an appropriate hardware accelerated 2.0 driver.

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard of an Android device that emulates opengl es 2.0 in software, not even the emulator can do so.

"OpenGL ES 2.0 is supported by most Android devices and is recommended for new applications being developed with OpenGL"

From: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html

You should read the sections "OpenGL Versions and Device Compatibiity" and "Choosing an OpenGL API version", and you should trust Google and not your coding team.